# Python: how to split a string by a delimiter that is invalid <0x0c>

Tags: python, split

I have a document which contain the charterer `<0x0c>`.
Using `re.split`.
The problem that it look like that:

```
import re
re.split('',text)
```

When although it works, you **CAN'T** see the charterer and except of living a nice comment it is a great candidate to be one of this legacy code that only I would understand.

How can I write it in a different, readable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express any character using escape codes. The [0x0C Form Feed ASCII codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed) can be expressed as `\f` or as `\x0c`:

```
re.split('\f', text)
```

See the [Python string and byte literals syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for more details on what escape sequences Python supports when defining a string literal value.

Note: you don't need to use the regex module to split on straight-up character sequences, you can just as well use `str.split()` here:

```
text.split('\f')
```